# Argument of type 'typeof Component' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Component>

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to have one service that opens different dialogs depending on from which components has service been called.

This is code from my service.
[pictureOfCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEsP4.png)

```
public addEditItem(origin: string, item?: MoneyModel|BudgetItemModel|WorkflowModel|SportItemModel) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.pickDialog(origin), {
      data: {
        item: item ? item : null,
        origin: origin,
      },
      width: '500px',
  });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        this.data.next(result);
        console.log('The dialog was closed', result ? result : 'by clicking on cancel');
    });
}

public pickDialog(origin: string) {
    switch (origin) {
      case 'workflow': return AddEditWorkflowItemComponent;
      case 'sport': return AddEditSportItemComponent;
    }
}
```

It works when I run it locally, but build fails because of this error:

*Argument of type 'typeof AddEditWorkflowItemComponent | typeof AddEditSportItemComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType | TemplateRef'.
  Type 'typeof AddEditSportItemComponent' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType | TemplateRef'.
    Type 'typeof AddEditSportItemComponent' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType'.
      Property 'authors' is missing in type 'AddEditSportItemComponent' but required in type 'AddEditWorkflowItemComponent'.*

Is there a way how I could convert the return from switch from typeof Component to ComponentType? Or, is there a way how I could switch the components that dialog opens in a better way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your image, the prop `authors` is missing from `AddEditSportItemComponent`, so to fix your problem, you can treat `pickDialog` method to return `any`:

```
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open((this.pickDialog(origin) as any), {
      data: {
        item: item ? item : null,
        origin: origin,
      },
      width: '500px',
  });
```

or create an interface which fit both `AddEditWorkflowItemComponent` and `AddEditSportItemComponent` and treat the method to return it.

```
export interface ComponentType<T = any> {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}

public pickDialog(origin: string): ComponentType {
    switch (origin) {
      case 'workflow': return AddEditWorkflowItemComponent;
      case 'sport': return AddEditSportItemComponent;
    }
}
```

if 2 class is distinct, and you want to using type safe, you will end up with create 2 different methods for each type.